# devstack ContextualVersionConflict

Tags: python, openstack, devstack

I am having the following error once I launch `stack.sh` in the last stable version:

```
sudo -H http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy= PIP_FIND_LINKS= SETUPTOOLS_SYS_PATH_TECHNIQUE=rewrite /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install -c /opt/stack/requirements/upper-constraints.txt -e /opt/stack/glance
2017-03-21 17:32:36.166 | Ignoring dnspython3: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
2017-03-21 17:32:36.404 | Obtaining file:///opt/stack/glance
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 | Exception:
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 | Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |     status = self.run(options, args)
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |     wb.build(autobuilding=True)
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |     self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |     ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 521, in _prepare_file
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |     req_to_install.check_if_exists()
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1036, in check_if_exists
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |     self.req.name
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in get_distribution
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |     dist = get_provider(dist)
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 432, in get_provider
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |     return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 968, in require
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |     needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 859, in resolve
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 |     raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
2017-03-21 17:32:38.075 | ContextualVersionConflict: (keystoneauth1 2.4.3 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('keystoneauth1>=2.16.0'), set(['castellan']))
2017-03-21 17:32:38.198 | +inc/python:pip_install:1                  exit_trap
2017-03-21 17:32:38.201 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:487                  local r=2
2017-03-21 17:32:38.204 | ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs -p
2017-03-21 17:32:38.207 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs=
2017-03-21 17:32:38.211 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:491                  [[ -n '' ]]
2017-03-21 17:32:38.215 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:497                  kill_spinner
2017-03-21 17:32:38.218 | +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:383               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2017-03-21 17:32:38.222 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:499                  [[ 2 -ne 0 ]]
2017-03-21 17:32:38.225 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:500                  echo 'Error on exit'
2017-03-21 17:32:38.225 | Error on exit
2017-03-21 17:32:38.235 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:501                  generate-subunit 1490117448 110 fail
2017-03-21 17:32:38.538 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:502                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2017-03-21 17:32:38.541 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:505                  /home/jbautista/Escritorio/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
2017-03-21 17:32:38.741 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  exit 2
```

It started failing today, tried to reinstall python but don't know whats exactly the problem

Answer (score 2):

Reading through the logs above, it seems to be an error because of the version conflict.

See the line: `ContextualVersionConflict: (keystoneauth1 2.4.3 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('keystoneauth1>=2.16.0'), set(['castellan']))`

Requirement is for keystoneauth1>=2.16.0 but your system contains keystoneauth1 2.4.3.

What you need to do is upgrade your keystoneauth1 package to its latest version or you can just uninstall the package causing problem and when you run the ./stack.sh script again, the setup will install the required package automatically.

```
$ sudo -H pip uninstall keystoneauth1
```

I hope this solves your issue.